# Is it possible to embed images into emails sent from tsql that will work on gmail?

Tags: t-sql, gmail

I have a tsql script

```
SET @body_custom = '<head>
                </head>
                <body>
                <img src="cid:testgif.gif" width="267" height="236" alt="">         
                </body>'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name = @dsysProfileName
, @recipients = 'email@gmail.com'
, @subject = 'SQl 2008 R2 Email Test'
, @body = @body_custom
, @body_format = 'HTML'
, @file_attachments = 'D:\testgif.gif'
```

And it attaches a file, and sends it to my email address, but instead of an image i see an empty square. Attachments are properly added. I tried using `src="testgif.gif"` but it also didn't work. Is there a way to attach an inline image to a message sent to gmail using only tsql?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, adding a link to a https server with the image path does work (the image shows) but I can't use it, it has to be a local imgae

Comment: try giving the absolute path to your image in the src field.

Answer (score 0):

Most email clients will block images for a host of security reasons. You may want to consider hosting the required images securely on a public site with a SSL certificate then referencing these via html image tags.